# Pystache: line break after partial

Tags: mustache

When including a partial in a Pystache template, a line break is added after the partial. For example, the template contains:

```
blah = {{> partial}};
```

Where `partial.mustache` is a single line file like:

```
{{#blubb}} "{{.}}" {{/blubb}}
```

The result is:

```
blah = "blubb1" "blubb2"
;
```

Is there a way to suppress that line break after the partial? (Is this an intended behavior even?)

Comment: Hi! Would you please show us explicitly where the \n are in your files? Also, you're welcome to join the discussion on https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended behavior is this:

- `' "{{.}}"\n'` is the content of your ('blubb') section tag.
- Expanding the 'blubb' section with the list `[ 'blubb1', 'blubb2' ]` should produce `' "blubb1"\n "blubb2"\n'`
- Expanding the partial in your template should therefore yield `blah =  "blubb1"\n "blubb2"\n;`

Removing the interstitial newline should be possible by rewriting your section tag as a single line, e.g. `{{#blubb}} "{{.}}"{{/blubb}}`.  This would, however, yield a result very much like the one you report if the partial file contained a trailing newline.

Comment: I agree with the intended behavior, although having everything on one line is not very human-readable if the partial involves several section tags. But even if my partial contains only one single line (so no trailing newline characters at all, unless the end of the file is treated as one), I get the result with the newline before the semicolon...

Comment: Many editors will ensure that the last character of a file is a newline; this is probably what you're encountering.

Comment: I've created an [issue](https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/61) with the spec proposing an alternate handling of trailing newlines for partials.

As far as the newlines in sections goes, I agree that it's a little unfortunate to have to write deeply nested sections on a single line. Dotted names (e.g. `{{# foo.bar.baz}}`) may help somewhat.  I'm reluctant to try introducing new syntax to support suppressing newlines for block sections without a really good use case, though.